# Не отображается RecyclerView в Activity с другим custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Делаю активити с RecyclerView, генерирую данные для TextView в функции generateFakeValue. В layout все есть, адаптер вроде без косяков, проект собирается без проблем, но списка по итогу нет на экране. Приложу код.

**CalendarActivity**

```
    class CalendarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCalendarBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCalendarBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.taskList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.taskList.adapter = Adapter(generateFakeValues())
    }

    private  fun generateFakeValues(): List<String>{
        val values = mutableListOf<String>()
        for(i in 0 .. 10){
            values.add("$i task ")
        }
        return values
    }

    class Adapter(private val values: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun getItemCount() = values.size

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val itemView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false)

            return ViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder?.textView?.text = values[position]
        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            private lateinit var binding: ListItemViewBinding
            var textView: TextView? = null

            init {
                textView = binding.taskTextView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_calendar_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalendarActivity">

    <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="446dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >

    </com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/task_list"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="288dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_item_view**

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.131"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/taskTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/taskTextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/taskTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.368"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете 2 разные разметки в своей активити. Одна создана через ViewBinding и не отображается, вторая отображается, но вы с ней не взаимодействуете (не устанавливаете адаптер и прочее).

Всему причина вот эти строки:

```
binding = ActivityCalendarBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar)
```

Вам надо разметку, загруженную через ViewBinding установить в качестве разметки для активити, как это описано в [документации](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities):

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: Подскажите, в каком месте нужно это прописать? В классе CalendarActivity пыталась, но после добавления приложение вылетает.

Comment: Замените строку setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar) на ту, что в ответе