# не получается изменять элементы в активити программно

Tags: android, kotlin

разметка:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/editlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayoutnamebutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">
    
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameplaintext"
                android:layout_width="362dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Заголовок"
                android:inputType="text" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Button"
                app:icon="@drawable/free_icon_microphone_3364184"
                app:iconGravity="top"
                app:iconSize="43dp"
                app:iconTint="#000000"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/addchecheckbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlistlayout"
                android:layout_width="411dp"
                android:layout_height="668dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutlist"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:text="CheckBox" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/noteplaintext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="Заметка"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

разметка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из кода я пытаюсь добавить кликлистенер элементам, изменить бакгроунд и отобразить выборочно какие-то, но ничего из этого не работает
способы программного воздействия на разметку правильны, ибо переписал этот экран на фрагмент и там все работало нормально , но мне нужен именно активити, и дело я так понимабю именнол в активити, ибо в других активити нет таких проблем

програмное изменение:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    var list = false
    binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.button.setOnClickListener {
        if (list){
            binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.nameplaintext.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext)
        }
        else {
             binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.nameplaintext.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext)
             binding.framelayout.noteplaintext.background  = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext)
        }
        binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.nameplaintext.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
            )
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
            binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.nameplaintext.background = null
            binding.framelayout.noteplaintext.background = null
        }
        binding.framelayout.noteplaintext.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
            )
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())


            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
             binding.linearlayoutnamebutton.nameplaintext.background = null
             binding.framelayout.noteplaintext.background  = null
        }
    }
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            val voice: ArrayList<String>? =
                data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) as ArrayList<String>
            binding.nameplaintext.setText(
                binding.nameplaintext.text.toString() + " " + voice?.get(0)
            )
        }
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            val voice: ArrayList<String>? =
                data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) as ArrayList<String>
            binding.noteplaintext.setText(
                binding.noteplaintext.text.toString() + " " + voice?.get(0)
            )
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: А где этот код, где вы программно изменяете элементы?

Comment: не видел смысла , но добавил на всякий случай

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288293/11515

Comment: т.е. код не работает, но добавить в вопрос этот самый код вы не видите смысла?

Comment: вопрос не относится к АС, не нужно добавлять эту метку

Comment: Да в теме, написанно что этот же код я использовал в фрагменте и в лругих активити и сюрприз(всо работало), а почему он не относится к ас, чем связан мой вопрос и вопрос с recyclerview